# Ionic 4 throwing errors on object keys returned from a http request call

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I have this function like this

```
if (form.valid) {
      this.api.resetPassword(this.otpcode).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          this.showToast(response.message);
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
        }
        if (response.error) {
          this.showToast(response.error);
        } else {
          this.errors = response.errors;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

However in VS Code I get an error on the lines trying to get the response e.g `response.success` that says `Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object | any[]'.
  Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)`.
I thought it was just a VS Code error and even after running ionic cordova build the same error appears in the console.

Comment: can you share your response object

Comment: please log the response detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what I did was first to add an exported variable and pass the response to it before trying to access the properties.

i.e

```
export class ForgotPasswordPage implements OnInit {
  response: any;
     ......
}
```

then I do

```
onVerify(form: NgForm) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.valid) {
      this.api.resetPassword(this.otpcode).subscribe(response => {
        this.response = response;
        if (this.response.success) {
          console.log(response);
          this.showToast(this.response.message);
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
        }
        if (this.response.error) {
          this.showToast(this.response.error);
        } else {
          this.errors = this.response.errors;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```